# Neo4J Cypher Query to Match Collections Against Other Collections

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new to Neo4J and really struggling on a query. This is not my actual domain, but I'm trying to simplify it down to a similar problem.

***Given:***

- a Region contains Markets
- a Market provides Fruit (e.g. Apple, Pear)
- a Market provides Vegetables (e.g. Cabbage, Broccoli)
- a Recipe requires Fruit (e.g. Apple, Peach)
- a Recipe requires Vegetables (e.g. Cabbage)

***I want:***

- the list of Recipes that can be satisfied by the Markets in my Region

Conceptually a way to solve this might be:

1. create a combined list of all Fruits provided by Markets in the Region
2. create a combined list of all Vegetables provided by Markets in Region
3. for each Recipe, check that its required Fruits are in the Fruit list
4. for each Recipe, check that its required Vegetables are in the Vegetable list
5. all Recipes that pass these checks are returned

Of course, a Cypher query will likely look very different from this. Any advice offered is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If anyone has a better title for this question, please advise. I recognize it's horrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that there is the following data scheme:

[image]

Then the query looks like this:

- for each potential recipe from the region, calculate the number of products that this region provides for this recipe
- for each potential recipe, calculate the number of required products
- compare

---

```
MATCH (R:Region {name: 'My Region'})-[:contains]->(M:Market)
                                    -[:provides]->(P:Product)
                                    <-[:requires]-(RC:Recipe)
WITH R, RC, 
        count(DISTINCT P) AS productsCountForRecipeByRegion
MATCH (RC)-[:requires]->(P:Product)
WITH R, RC, productsCountForRecipeByRegion, 
     count(P) as productsCountForRecipe 
     WHERE productsCountForRecipeByRegion = productsCountForRecipe
RETURN R, RC
```